# Server not response to WebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I should write program for working with some web-site. It's use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse for send and receive data to\from server. First of all, my program authorize on this site, then prepare data and send it. When I run my program on developer's PC, it's works great, without any problem, but when my program runs on client's PC it's not work. I remotely connected to client's PC for get program's log and compare it with my log. Client is our partner and he get me his password for testing. Ok, I compare log's and it's the same! The only difference is response to last request: on my PC I receive html page, but client's PC generate timeout exception. First, I thought, that problem is client's firewall, but how my program get authentication's cookie and session's id info? I outputed all WebRequest's parameters and compare it, but it's the same, as I already said.

Can anybody tell me, what may be reason of this bug and how I can resolve it?

Comment: You should post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your code it will make this incredibly difficult, you should have several pieces of error handling and validation to help determine the location of the error.  An example would be:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://stackoverflow.com") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = NetworkCredentials(@"username", @"password");
request.Timeout = 300;

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(request))
     throw new Exception("Error in Request");

using(var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
     using(var writer = File.Create(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))
          stream.CopyTo(writer);
```

I would highly recommend using Fiddler or the browser to analyze the response / request as well.  It should show you a large chunk of those details.

Without code we can't be more of help.

Comment: My code is the same, but I manually adding some header and cookies. I already use Fiddler. It's really great program, my program was wrote by data, that was got by Fiddler (site don't have official API).

Comment: Well, the code above works quite well.  Try it to get the content your attempting to request, if it fails then may be an issue not within the application.  If it works then your API has a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I already said, that I make request to the same client's url (client's url is "http:\\site.com\1234" and url's, which I use is "http:\\site.com\1234") and I use his login and password. I get html page, but client have exception. On my PC, I use internet by proxy, client connected to internet without it, but I don't manually set proxy's settings, my program use default.

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot to close response stream. I don't know how, but on the my PC Fiddler automatically close it, but user's PC don't have Fiddler... When I just added: responseStream.Close() after reading operation, server start to response to all request.

Comment: @Mixim Yeah, that is why I use the `using` so as soon as it leaves the scope it implements `IDispose`.

Answer (score 0):

I ve once faced the same problem when I was using Win XP and my client was using Vista. These webrequest and webesponse calls were internally converted to SOAP calls and were transmitted using one of the internet explorer dll. the default timeout in XP was > default timeout for Vista requests. after discussing with client's infrastructure team we changed the timeout and that is how issue was resolved. As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) default timeout is 100 seconds.

Comment: I know about it, that's why I manually set timeout to 120000ms, and OS is the same Win7